# How can I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to create a Mailing Lable Word document?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, office-interop

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDocument = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
oDocument = oWord.Documents.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.MailingLabel oLable = oWord.MailingLabel;

oDocument = oLable.CreateNewDocument();
oDocument.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory.ToString() + SaveFileDialog1.FileName);
oWord.Quit();
```

I can get an empty Word Lable document from the code above, how can I input data into the document? Anybody can give me an example of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you write content in file.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDocument = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
        oDocument = oWord.Documents.Add();

        BigInteger r = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
        {
            r = r * i;             
        }
        Console.Write(r.ToString());

        oDocument.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
        oDocument.Content.Text = r.ToString();

        oDocument.SaveAs(@"d:\mydoc.docx");
        oWord.Quit();
```

you can find more info here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/